# 疑似パラメータとポリシー変数の共存

Tags: aws, aws-cloudformation, aws-iam

下記のコードでCloudFormationでIAMグループを作成しました。
${aws:username}は、下記のリンクの[IAM ポリシーエレメントのポリシー変数に使用可能なリクエスト情報](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_variables.html#policy-vars-formoreinfo)を使いました。

AWS AccountIdの部分もリテラルではなく変数を使う方法はないでしょうか。

下記は試してみましたがいずれもだめでした。

Resource: "arn:aws:iam::${aws:userid}:user/${aws:username}"
ポリシー変数は、IAMユーザは、AWSアカウントではなく一意IDが返されるからかもしれませんが、確認方法がわかりませんでした。

Resource: !Sub "arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:user/${aws:username}"
ClodFormationの疑似パラメータを使いましたが、ポリシー変数と同じ${}表記なので、エラーになりました。

```
Type: "AWS::IAM::Group"
Properties:
  GroupName: "Users"
  Policies:
    - PolicyName: group-user-policy
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - "iam:GetAccountPasswordPolicy"
            Resource: "*"
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - "iam:ChangePassword"
            Resource: !Sub "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:user/${aws:username}"
```

Answer (score 1):

CloudFormationの`Fn::Join`関数を用いると可能かと思われます。

- [Fn::Join - AWS CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-join.html)

cfn-iam-group.yml

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Description: A sample template
Parameters:
  IAMUserArn:
    Type: String
    Default: arn:aws:iam::1234567890:user/user-name

Resources:
  IAMGroup:
    Type: "AWS::IAM::Group"
    Properties:
      GroupName: "Users"
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: group-user-policy
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - "iam:GetAccountPasswordPolicy"
                Resource: "*"
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - "iam:ChangePassword"
                Resource: !Join
                  - ''
                  - - 'arn:aws:iam::'
                    - !Sub "${AWS::AccountId}:"
                    - 'user/${aws:username}'
```

```shell
aws cloudformation deploy
    --template-file ./cfn-iam-group.yml 
    --stack-name cfn-iam-group 
    --capabilities CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM 
    --parameter-overrides IAMUserArn="arn:aws:iam::1234567890:user/user-name"
```

- `Fn::Join`関数で与えられた文字列配列を連結
- 配列の要素に`Fn::Sub`関数を用いて擬似パラメータ`AWS::AccountId`を参照

IAM Groupが作成され、以下のようなポリシーがアタッチされていることが確認できました。

[image: IAM Group Policy]